# getRow for nested row

Tags: tabulator

I have a table with nested datatree, I need to collapse particular rows but can't seem to get the row instance of the nested row.  I can use the index of the top-level rows to do table.getRow(1) but table.getRow(2) fails. I can get the row instance of row 68 which is the next top-level row, so it seems I can't get row(2) because it is a child of row(1).  is there an alternate way to get child rows? table.getRow(1).getRow(2)?

Comment: It would really help if you added some of your code and a screenshot or visual aid showing your table

Comment: sorry, I'm working with a whole bunch of business sensitive information, didn't have time to make a table of dummy data before I left for the day. I thought my explanation was pretty clear: I can easily get handles for the top-level rows, but not any child rows using the built-in table.getRows() function and I couldn't find a function that gives me the child rows even if I know their ID number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check [documentation](http://tabulator.info/docs/4.2/tree#component) check this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dota2pro/0gLb1v2x/32/) and check console

```
use `var children = row.getTreeChildren();`

// Get all rows
 const allRows = table.getRows();
  console.log('allRows',allRows);

 const firstRow = table.getRow(1);
  console.log('firstRow',firstRow);

const firstRowChildren =  firstRow.getTreeChildren();
  console.log('firstRowChildren',firstRowChildren);


$('#toggle').click(function(){
firstRow.treeToggle();
});
```

Comment: so the table.getRow() function won't work for child rows, but row.getTreeChildren() gets me an array.  then I can search through that array for the particular ones I need to close.  not as simple as table.getRow() but it shouldn't be too tricky. thanks.

Comment: ```
 for (var x = 0; x< rowsToLeaveOpen.length; x++){
  subLevel1 = table.getRow(level1[x]).getTreeChildren();
  for (var y = 0; y< subLevel1.length; y++){
   subLevel2 = subLevel1[y].getTreeChildren();
   for (var z = 0; z< subLevel2.length; z++){
    //check if I need to collapse
   }
   //check if I need to collapse
  }
 }
 ```